# Creating micro black holes with "bosers"; easier than creating kugelblitzes?

Tags: black-holes, bose-einstein-condensate

A "boser" is a coherent matter beam or pulse of Bose-Einstein condensate (and a spin of the word "laser"), sometimes portrayed in science fiction but maybe [becoming more a reality](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/275/5300/617.1.summary). A kugelblitz black hole is a concentration of EM radiation so dense that space-time curves into a black hole.

Kugelblitz black holes are thought to be absurdly difficult to produce because of the energy requirement. Because E=mc^2, a kugelblitz black hole requires more energy for a given mass equivalent in ordinary baryonic matter than ordinary baryonic matter. *C* is a large number to be divided by.

So, the question. Firstly, can we even conceptually create a black hole with bosers? (Do particles hate being so close together, even if in phase, so much as to make the idea impossible?) If it is possible, would bosers be "easier" or less costly in energy over lasers? (I'm not talking about the energy used to produce the laser/boser beams, but instead the energy of the beams themselves.)

Comment: It's not just "becoming more a reality."  The first atom laser (which is the normal term, not "boser") was produced over twenty years ago, by Wolfgang Ketterle's lab at MIT.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is still getting enough mass into the Schwarzschild radius. The wavelength of a particle is $\lambda=h/p$, so in order to get $N$ particles into a region of radius $r=2GNm/c^2$ they need to have $\lambda\approx r$, or $$\frac{hc^2}{2G} < Nmp.$$ For helium nuclei moving at 0.1c I get $N\approx 10^{38}$, which is actually a macroscopic amount (about the mass of a mountain). That better be an intense boser.

Comment: Very concise and intuitive answer, thank you!